# what's the differences between DOM node Object and JS Object?

Tags: javascript

As we all know, we can use Object.defineProperty() to define some properties of an Object, but when i run the below code, it throw an error! I think there may be some difference between Dom object and js Object{}. I'll very appreciate if anyone can help me out!

```
var inn = document.getElementById("search_form_input");//a input element
inn.nodeType;// 1 elementNode
inn.value;//output the value
typeOf(inn);//object
// inn is an Object , so I try the below function
Object.defineProperties(inn,'value',{
    set:function(){
       return console.log("setting inn value")
    }
})
```

This produces the following error:

```
VM710:1 Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: v
   at Function.defineProperties (<anonymous>)
   at <anonymous>:1:8
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing Object.defineProperties and Object.defineProperty.

Check both functions documentation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

> Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

> Object.defineProperties(obj, props)

Assuming you wanted to use `Object.defineProperty`, your code works if you use the right function :

```js
var inn = document.getElementById("search_form_input");//a input element
inn.nodeType;// 1 elementNode
inn.value;//output the value
console.log(typeof inn);//object
// inn is an Object , so I try the below function
Object.defineProperty(inn,'value',{
    set:function(){
       return console.log("setting inn value")
    }
});

inn.value = "test";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search_form_input"/>
```

Comment: spelling error! I have realized my problem, thank you very much

Comment: There is another question: when I changed the `inn.value` by text some value in the input element, the set:function is expected to excuted , but the fact is not！Could you please help me!

Comment: If you have another issue, you should ask a new question. More people will be able to help you. And I will be glad too help if I can.

Comment: My level is too low to ask a new question again, thanks for you replying.mybe I should try to fix it by myself.haha

Comment: Ok. Well, about that issue. In the snippet I added to the answer, the set function is called when setting the inn.value property.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.defineProperties(obj, props)` has 2 parameters, the second one being an object. You are passing a string as second parameter.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties